# SoftReference / WeakReference Nullpointer

Tags: java, android

Receiving a NPE on the below line

```
if( mCache.containsKey(key) ){
```

Trying to use SoftReference WeakReference with hashmap while decodingFile image with the below code.

```
private WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache;

public Bitmap get(String key, BmpWrap image, BitmapFactory.Options options){

            File root = mContext.getFilesDir();
            String name = Activity.fullScreenActive ? image.name + ".png" : image.name
                    + ".stat.png";
            File img = new File(root, name);

            if(key == null){
                return null;
            }
            if( mCache.containsKey(key) ){
                SoftReference<Bitmap> reference = mCache.get(key);
                image.bmp = reference.get();
                if( image.bmp != null ){
                    return image.bmp;
                }
                image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                mCache.put(key, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(image.bmp));
                return image.bmp;
            }

            if( img.exists() ){
                image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                mCache.put(key, new SoftReference<Bitmap>(image.bmp));
                return image.bmp;
            } else{
                throw new RuntimeException("Boooom!");
            }
        }

        private void scaleImage(BmpWrap image, BitmapFactory.Options options)

        {
            options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * IMG_BUFFER_LEN];
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
            options.inDither = false;


            try {
                Field f = options.getClass().getField("inPurgeable");
                f.set(options, Boolean.TRUE);

                Field f2 = options.getClass().getField("inInputShareable");
                f2.set(options, Boolean.TRUE);
            } catch (Exception ignore) {
            }

            File root = mContext.getFilesDir();
            String name = Activity.fullScreenActive ? image.name + ".png" : image.name
                    + ".stat.png";
            File img = new File(root, name);

            // maybe it's jpeg
            if (!img.exists()) {
                img = new File(root, name.replace(".png", ".jpg"));
            }

            if (img.exists()) {

                if (image.bmp == null || Activity.fullScreenSwitch) {
                    if (image.bmp != null)
                    image.bmp.recycle();
                    image.bmp = null;
                    **get(name, image, options);**
                    //image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath(), options);
                } else if (image.bmp == null) {
                    image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                            getResourceByString(image.name), options);
                }
            } else {
                image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        getResourceByString(image.name), options);
            }
        }
```

Stack

```
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Boooom!
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.apk.View$Thread.get(View.java:259)
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.apk.View$Thread.scaleImage(View.java:296)
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.apk.View$Thread.resizeImages(View.java:326)
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.apk.View$Thread.setSurfaceSize(View.java:515)
12-16 18:30:42.724: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at com.apk.View.surfaceChanged(View.java:889)
```

Comment: Wait, are you sure you want a WeakReference to a SoftReference to a Bitmap?

Comment: Under some circumstances I receive OOM on the commented line under the get method call. So hoping to implement this to stop those crashes.

Comment: Sure, but what's wrong with just a normal WeakHashMap<String, Bitmap>?

Comment: How could I integrate that in my current code example above?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is,(**This is for NPE**)

```
private WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache;
```

Something like,

```
private WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache = new WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>>();
```

Try this and let me know what happen..

Comment: Stopped NPE but now it Throws the RunTimeException throw new RuntimeException("Boooom!"); Not sure about the routine where I null and recycle the bitmaps in scaleImage might neeed to make some modifications to routine now I am using soft reference.

Comment: Think the image did not exist yes.

Comment: Yes images are on img.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: If you replace the get() call with

Comment: image.bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath(), options); the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException means that `mCache` is null when you're trying to access it. And your RuntimeException happens because the file in the memory with the given name doesn't exist.

Also, you didn't ask this in the question, but it seems a proper thing to say. Why do you need to use WeakHashMap? It is used to allow GC to collect entries whose *keys* are no longer referenced anywhere. You use strings as keys, why do you want to depend on whether they are reachable or not? The mechanism is supposed to let the bitmaps be garbage collected, so an ordinary HashMap to SoftReferences is what you actually need.

Comment: An example of what? An example of map would obviously be `private Map<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache`.

Comment: Erase the line `private WeakHashMap<String, SoftReference<Bitmap>> mCache;`, enter my line.